# Disparador con consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente, cuando se ingrese un registro a la tabla pedidos se realice un disparador que realice la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, fechaDeSolicitud, now()) <= 120 FROM pedidos
 WHERE idPedido= (aqui iria el id del pedido que ingreso como registro)
```

Pero necesito que se repita hasta que el resultado de esta consulta de 0

(Devolverá 1 si aún no han pasado 120 minutos o 0 en caso contrario)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo así no sea con un disparador? muchas gracias.

Comment: La consulta no devuelve nada y la comparación <= 120 en el SELECT no tiene sentido.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Si lo devuelve, ya lo comprobé.

Comment: Mil disculpas! Se me fue la olla! Pues yo te recomendaría exactamente lo que dices un trigger después de cada inserción en la tabla que pides que ejecute un loop while hasta que la condición sea falsa.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaria hacer un evento cada cierto tiempo, hay opciones de refrescar automaticamente en javascript o usar un boton para actualizar manualmente. y llamar a una funcion que te devuelva la respuesta de 0 o 1.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` FUNCTION `menor_a_120`(fechaDeSolicitud datetime) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE valor INT;
    SET @diferencia_minutos=(SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, fechaDeSolicitud, now()) );
    IF (@diferencia_minutos<=120) THEN
        SET valor=0;
    ELSE
        SET valor=1;
    END IF;
RETURN valor;
END
```

y luego en tu javascript mandas una consulta y ves que es lo que te devuelve, asi no cargas tanto trabajo a la base de datos.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que puede no estar utililzando javascript, en cuyo caso enviaría la consulta directamente.

Comment: en php seria 
<?php 
header("Refresh: 30; URL='pagina.php'");
?>
donde 30 son los segundos, lo ideal es no dejar la carga de trabajo en la base de datos y hacerlo de otra manera para no llegar a afectar a los otros procesos

Comment: Y en javascript se podría hacer : setInterval(()=>$.get(url).then(...), 30000); Pero y si la comunicación se hace por ejemplo desde una aplicación de escritorio? El autor no ha aportado datos de cual es el tipo de cliente. Por lo que veo la respuesta de @Juan Manuel Doren la más apropiada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo así, aunque advierto que no lo he probado :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_pedidos AFTER INSERT ON pedidos
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1;
        WHILE v1 > 0 DO
          SET v1 = (SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, fechaDeSolicitud, now()) <= 120 FROM pedidos
                    WHERE idPedido= (aqui iria el id del pedido que ingreso como registro))
        END WHILE;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo la consulta podría estar 120 minutos esperando por la condición. Lo mejor si estás usando linux es hacer un proceso que haga ese trabajo y que se ejecute por ejemplo cada 1 minuto, lo inscribes en el crontab

http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

Answer (score 0):

No veo mucho sentido crear un *trigger* que ejecute una consulta, a no ser que el resultado de esa consulta sea guardado en una tabla temporal o en una variable que puedas usar en otra parte de tu proyecto.

Si quieres hacer algo así, se me ocurre esto:

```sql
-- Opcion 1: Almacenar el resultado en una variable
delimiter $$
create trigger tr_pedidos_ai 
after insert on pedidos
for each row
begin
    SELECT timestampdiff(MINUTE, fechaDeSolicitud, now()) <= 120 
        INTO @ts_diff
    FROM pedidos
    WHERE idPedido=new.id_pedido;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

En alguna otra parte de tu aplicación, puedes ejecutar esta consulta:

```sql
select @ts_diff;
```

que devolverá el valor que te interesa.

Ahora bien, también puedes crear una función que ejecute la consulta y devuelva lo que quieres, y llamar a esa función cuando lo necesites:

```sql
delimiter $$
create function ts_diff(id int) returns int
begin
    declare diff int;
    select timestampdiff(MINUTE, fechaDeSolicitud, now()) <= 120
        into diff
    from pedidos
    where idPedido = id;
    return coalesce(diff, 0);
end $$
delimiter;
```

Y puedes ejecutar esta función cada vez que lo necesites en alguna otra parte de tu aplicación:

```sql
set @idPedido = 1; -- valor de prueba
select ts_diff(@idPedido);
```